# Replace `<a-cursor>` ring with an image in aframe

Tags: aframe

Is there any way I can use an image as a `<a-cursor>`.

```
<a-cursor>

</a-cursor>
```

I tried to put an `<a-image>` inside it but it doesn't works for me.

Comment: Is there anyone that can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place the image as a sibling of a-cursor and wrap both with the camera. Here's an example:

```
  <a-entity id="main-camera-wrapper">
    <a-camera id="main-camera">
      <a-cursor id="fuse-cursor" material="opacity: 0;" position="0 0 -1"></a-cursor>
      <a-image src="#my-image" position="0 0 -.99"></a-image>
    </a-camera>
  </a-entity>
```

Comment: Is there any css for the id's that you have included ?

Comment: Cool, the id's are just there for semantics, but not necessarily needed unless your hooking into Javascript later on.